# How to work with QGraphicsScene::addPixmap when it only accepts const QPixmap?

Tags: qt, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsscene, qimage, qpixmap

I'd like to display some `QImage` through `QGraphicsScene`, my code's very straightforward:

**mainwindow.h**

```
QImage *sourceImage;
QGraphicsView *imageView;
QGraphicsScene *imageScene;
```

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
imageScene = new QGraphicsScene;
imageView = new QGraphicsView;
imageView->setScene(imageScene);

sourceImage = new QImage;
sourceImage.load(":/targetimage.png");
imageScene.addPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(sourceImage));
```

And then the complier points out exactly what I did wrong: [`QGraphicsScene::addPixmap`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsscene.html) accepts only `const QPixmap` as argument, and I was trying to convert `QImage` to `const QPixmap`, which is not allowed because `QPixmap::fromImage` within only accept `const QImage`, like a `const` hell.

The [official documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsscene.html) on this method doesn't make much sense to me either, if I'd like to make for example, an image viewer, and during runtime I'd sure load different images into `QImage sourceImage`, and how can I accomplish that using a `const QImage`?

This problem has been agonizing, thanks for any advice. Moreover could you light me a bit if there's any vision on the philosophical reason why guys in Qt make these methods `const`?

Comment: What prevents you from using QPixmaps instead of QImages?

Comment: I'm working with opencv as well, which means I'll constanly convert `cv::Mat` to `QImage` and back. `QPixmap` is optimized for display, according to documentation. I believe there is some ways to convert `QPixmap` to cv::Mat but `QImage` fit the problem space perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
imageScene.addPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(*sourceImage));
```

Some advice:

there is no need to allocate the QImage on the heap (using new).
Use:

```
QImage sourceImage;
```

Then you do not need to dereference the pointer when calling `QPixmap::fromImage`

Just to clarify: the constness has nothing to do with the error.

Comment: That's simple and inspiring. I've done some reading on pointers and update my C++ knowledge, but I couldn't resist asking, since `sourceImage` points to what's type `QImage` not `const QImage`, why does methods like `QPixmap::fromImage(const QImage)` still accepts `*sourceImage` as a valid argument?

Comment: Because the restriction is only in one way. If the method has a const parameter, this means a promise not to change what you pass into it. 
If it were the other way around, you passing a const object as a non-const parameter, you would give something that should never be modified to a function that states 'I will modify this'

Comment: While that addresses one issue timfeirg seemed to be having (not understanding that a const param to a function is just a promise by the function not to alter that param), that doesn't answer the question he's asking there, which is:

Why does a function which has a documented signature that says it only takes an object as a param, instead accept a POINTER to that object as a param? How does that even compile?

I don't have an answer to that. I think it's some kinda magic.

Comment: The function does not accept a pointer. `*sourceImage` is not a pointer, you are dereferencing a pointer (with the `*` operator), so you get the object itself. The type of `*sourceImage`is `QImage` which is acceptable for a parameter of type `const QImage`. You give it something that can be modified, but the function says 'I will not modify it', which is ok.